# R - Fastest / Most Efficient way to convert data of a column in a data frame?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

I have a 5,000,000 x 6 data frame.

One of the columns, `tweetSendTime`, is a timestamp, which I want to change to a POSIX format so I can do things like `df["tweetSendTime"] > SPECIFIC_GLOBAL_VARIABLE_DATE`.

Currently, I use

```
foreach(j=1:len) %dopar%
{
    sendTime = combinedDF[j, "tweetSendTime"]
    ## Current format - Thu Jan 14 19:44:46  0000 2016
    sendTime = gsub(" 0000", " +0000", sendTime)
    updatedTime = strptime( sendTime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
    combinedDF[j, "tweetSendTime"] = toString(updatedTime)
}
```

However, I am not convinced that this is the most efficient way to do this.  Is there a better / faster way to update this array?

Comment: I tried your code and it seems pretty fast to me, I just don't understand why are you turning updateTime to string instead of keep a POSIXct...

Comment: It seems that you could pass whole `$tweetSendTime` to `gsub` and `strptime` at once

Comment: You can skip the `gsub` entirely and just specify `tz = 'UTC'` in `strptime`, since they're all `+0000` anyway. You'll need to put `0000` in the format, e.g. `strptime(sendTime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S 0000 %Y", tz = 'UTC')`.

Comment: Actually, you can vectorize the whole thing: `strptime(combinedDF$tweetSendTime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S 0000 %Y", tz = 'UTC')

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the loop (I'm pretty distracted today, and I tried your code without the loop)... you don't need the for-loop at all... just remove the loop and indices `j` and you're done! (and remove final toString, that's useless IMO)

Answer (score 1):

R is vectorized; you don't need to do this in a loop. In fact, the loop will slow things down dramatically. You can convert the entire column in one command (edit, per digEmAll):

```
combinedDF$tweetSendTime = strptime(gsub(" 0000", " +0000", combinedDF$tweetSendTime), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
```

Also check out [as.POSIX*](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/as.POSIXlt); that may work for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks! This is what I was looking for.  However, it gave me a weird error. "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "tweetSendTime", value = list(`Wed Dec 23 20:18:17  0000 2015.sec` = 17,  : 
  replacement has 44934725 rows, data has 4084975".  The original data.frame was slightly smaller than my estimate, it was 4,084,975x6.

Comment: [`foreach` is not `for`](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-wonders-of-foreach/); in fact it can be a lot faster than `*apply`.

Comment: You don't need sapply at all. It's just: `combinedDF$tweetSendTime = strptime(gsub(" 0000", " +0000", combinedDF$tweetSendTime), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")`